# Why is the MPIA a stopgap measure and cannot fully replace the Appellate Body in the WTO?

Tags: wto

> In March 2020, the European Union and 15 other WTO members agreed to a
> Multiparty Interim Appeal Arbitration Arrangement (MPIA). This created
> an alternative appellate body while the official WTO body is not
> functional. It mirrors the usual WTO appeal rules and can be
> voluntarily used between any WTO members to resolve disputes. The
> European Commissioner for Trade Phil Hogan said: "This is a stop-gap
> measure to reflect the temporary paralysis of the WTO's appeal
> function for trade disputes ... We will continue our efforts to
> restore the appeal function of the WTO dispute settlement system as a
> matter of priority."[4] Since being announced, the People's Republic
> of China and other WTO member nations have joined the MPIA.[5]

https://wtoplurilaterals.info/plural_initiative/the-mpia/

Why is the MPIA a stopgap measure and cannot fully replace the Appellate Body in the WTO? As you may know, the United States blocked the selection of judges of the Appellate Body of the Dispute Settlement Mechanism (WTOAB) since 2019, resulting in the WTO Appellate Body being shut down due to a shortage of judges. Since then the EU instituted the MPIA, but why is the MPIA a lesser stopgap measure and cannot fully replace the WTOAB process?

Comment: You've kinda asked this before https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77065/is-the-reliance-of-the-mpia-making-the-wto-less-effective but got no answer because it's kinda obvious, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the US hasn't signed up to MPIA, and insofar it says it doesn't intend to, duh. Consequently MPIA has heard [no US-related cases](https://arbitrationblog.kluwerarbitration.com/2023/08/11/three-years-of-the-multi-party-interim-appeal-arbitration-arrangement-an-interim-evaluation-of-arbitration-as-a-means-to-appeal-wto-panel-reports/). And the US [still used](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2667111523000154) the old appeal mechanism, knowing that is going nowhere, the so-called "appeal into oblivion". To be fair here, some other countries like Turkey also haven't signed up to MPIA. But Turkey did agree to an ad-hoc arbitration appeal mechanism for one case. The US has (unofficially) [said](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83167/18373) they might agree to something like that [i.e. consent to appeals on a case-by-case basis], but insofar they haven't agreed in any concrete appeal case, AFAICT.

[BTW](https://riskandcompliance.freshfields.com/post/102idx0/wto-dispute-settlement-update-frozen-fries-put-the-mpia-to-the-test),

> Some WTO members have amended their national legislation allowing them to adopt remedies where the losing party appeals into the void. The EU amended its Enforcement Regulation to this effect, also widening the scope of possible measures that can be used to retaliate.

Even though they've pretty much legislated the mechanism for a (mutual) trade war, right now the US and EU are avoiding more confrontations on that though, due to other geopolitical alignments, like the war in Ukraine.